# How to automatically capture an image from a video in opencv?

Tags: python, image, opencv, video, detection

So ive already created a program that can identify what its looking at eg, person, car etc. Is there a way that i can code it with so that whenever it looks at a car it snaps a pic?

Heres my code:

```
cap = cv2.VideoCapture("y2mate.com - 4K Streets of New York USA  City Walking Tour  Short Preview Video_1080p.mp4")


#Check if the video is opened correctly
if not cap.isOpened():
    
    cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
if not cap.isOpened():
    raise IOError
    
font_scale = 3
font = cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_PLAIN

while True:
    ret,frame = cap.read()
    
    ClassIndex, confidece, bbox = model.detect(frame,confThreshold=0.6)
        
    print(ClassIndex)
    if (len(ClassIndex)!=0):
        for ClassInd, conf, boxes in zip(ClassIndex.flatten(), confidece.flatten(), bbox):
            if (ClassInd<=80):
                cv2.rectangle(frame,boxes,(255, 0, 0), 2)
                cv2.putText(frame,classLabels[ClassInd-1],(boxes[0]+10,boxes[1]+40), font, fontScale=font_scale,color=(0, 255, 0), thickness = 3)
    
    cv2.imshow('Object Detection', frame)
    
    if cv2.waitKey(2) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break
        
cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: `if car: cv2.imwrite(frame, ...)` ?

Comment: i dont get it furas can u elaborate?

Comment: when you recognize car then simply use `cv2.imwrite` to save `frame` and you have snapshot.

Comment: but when i tried adding yours in it didnt work, do u have any alternatives?

Comment: where do i add it in